# Erasing stroke on two separate segments of shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I want to have a shape with a fill and in some segments the stroke should be removed. Can this be resolved somehow using e.g. the path finder?

This image shows (a very simplified version of) what I want:

[image]

I can easily do this using two separate shapes (one for stroke, one for fill) but I would like to do it using one shape.

The following question solves the problem for only one cut, but 
I want two or more: [Erasing part of a shape with a stroke in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6985/erasing-part-of-a-shape-with-a-stroke-in-illustrator#)

As suggested, here is the actual shape in question. I would like the horizontal line at the top to have no stroke as shown here.

[image]

Comment: That example you give just now is achieved way easier with a clipping mask hiding part of the orange shape.

Comment: @Vincent I am aware of this and obviously this is a very simple problem but for more complex problems I wanted to know if there is a way of modifying the stroke of each segment separately, apparently this is not possible. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a totally different situation and answer. Add an **Opacity Mask** to the shape.

[image: MASK]

Here a detailed info about how to create an **Opacity Mask** https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/109186/120647

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice workaround but I will wait to accept it if there is some other way of doing it. Especially appreciate the video explanation, how did you do it?

Comment: There are many online tools for it you can download for free.

Comment: why would you want to use an opacity mask rather than a clipping mask?

Comment: two different options, I think there are more than a way to solve this. The question is talking about a single shape, which I think is not possible in any case. Anyway, those question types that change the objetive as the answers come up are always very conflicting, for the questioner, for the respondent and for future users.

Answer (score 4):

With Illustrator, thinking in a vector way:

[image: CIRCLE 1]

[image: CIRCLE2]

Comment: Thank you, maybe I should've clarified that the shape is far more complex and I want more than two splits.

Comment: Put the real shape at the question, sure there will be a solution.

Comment: Updated with actual shape in question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's some hope to do it as one shape. You can adjust stroke dashes to the right lengths and places. It needs some tinkering and the result isn't easily forced to exact predetermined dimensions.

Another way to make it formally as one shape is to have a custom pattern brush. The pattern can be 2 rectangles. The result an have exact dimensions. In practice the shape of course is a combination and not easier to do than 2 or 3  separate shapes

Here's a screenshot of the pattern brush option version and the brush settings. Two colored rectangles are drawn and dragged simultaneously to the brushes collection:

[image]

Then a black circle has got a stroke which applies the new brush.

Dimensionally perfect result is got easily if you have 2 copies of your shape - one without stroke, only the fill and one without a fill, only the stroke.

Clip from the stroke the needed parts off with the scissors tool or hide them with a clipping or opacity mask as in your old example, The mask can be a group, if needed.

About Pathfinder: It can be used. You can expand the stroke-only version ie. transform the stroke to a filled path. Then you can with pathfinder panel subtract a shape from it or make an intersection. This is useless, if you absolutely for some reason need a single shape version.